# OkHttp - can't use basic string API methods on result

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm using a custom API in my code and calling it using OkHttp. At the moment I can print the result to a text view as a string, but I can't use standard string methods like indexOf or contains, whenever I try to, the app shuts down. Am I formatting it wrong?

The result gets returned as:

```
String result = response.body().string();
```

I can print this to a Text view, but

```
if (result.contains("No users found"))
    {
        return "false";
    }
```

closes the app.

Complete code:

```
public class CallAPI extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
private final String API_URL = url;

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
private String body;
Response response;
private static String result;


public CallAPI(String body)
{
    this.body = body;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
    this.body = body;
    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain");
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, this.body);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(API_URL)
            .get()
            .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
            .post(body)
            .build();

    try {
        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        result = response.body().string();
        return result;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public String getResult() throws IOException {
    //This is where the app closes
    if (result.contains("No users found"))
    {
        return "false";
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post logs ?

Comment: `closes the app.` with a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 //This is where the app closes
```

But only if `result== null` or not initialized.

So check for null before use.

```
private static String result;
```

That is wrong to begin with.

From where and when do you call `getResult()`?

Your code looks awfully wrong.

You should handle the result of doInBackground in onPostExecute.

Comment: It gets called from another class, which I can't show because it contains too much of the company's data, but this gives the same problem. Sorry if it's a bit unclear.

Comment: What gets called? Do not use getResult! Use onPostExecute with an interface or other callback to handle the result. Do away with that private static string.